# What is the best heuristic function for evaluating the state in game of sprouts?

Tags: heuristics, game-theory, computer-games

We are developing game of sprouts bot using min-max algorithm. We need a good heuristic function for evaluating the state of the game/player. Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Perhaps you could give a link to a description of Sprouts, say on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprouts_(game).

Comment: I doubt there exists a "best" heuristic.  There are probably many different alternatives, each with their own tradeoffs (e.g., between simplicity vs accuracy).  What approaches have you considered so far?  Have you come up with any candidate heuristics yourself?